# Remove .php extension from an url. But before last value

Tags: php

I have a url i.e. http://searchberry.co/search.php/2731804/?query=admin. I have to remove .php from the url.

And the url that i need i.e. http://searchberry.co/search/2731804/?query=admin

Comment: You can use `str_replace('.php', '', $url);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$url=preg_replace("/\.php/","",$url,1);
```

others suggested using str_replace, but that will remove every instance of `.php`, what happens if the query is `?query=lol.php` ? the query will be edited to `query=lol`, unfortunately it seems str_replace doesn't support a limit, but preg_replace does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use str_replace php function

```
$url =  "http://searchberry.co/search.php/2731804/?query=admin";

$str = str_replace(".php", "", $url);
echo $str;
```

[here is](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) some documentation about this function

EDIT 
try something like this

```
$url =  "http://searchberry.co/search.php/2731804/?query=admin.php";

function str_rep_first_occ($from, $to, $content)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}

echo str_rep_first_occ('.php', '', $url);
```

Comment: Ok Sir, But search.php is name of a file.

Comment: And the url  http://searchberry.co/search.php/2731804/?query=admin is the form action

Comment: otoh, this will remove every instance of ".php", what happens if the query is `?query=lol.php`   ?   the query will be edited to `query=lol` - you should add a limit to it

Comment: @hanshenrik fixed

Comment: @RahulKumat did what you asked sir

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read on apache mod_rewrite (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

create a .httpaccess in your route folder and add the following lines based on your root directory

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase "/var/www/htdocs"
   RewriteRule ^search/([-\w]+)/$ search.php/([-\w]+)/$1 [NC,L]
</Directory>
```